# need a bash script to check its OS version

Tags: bash

We have two scripts separately for 64 Bit and 32 Bit.

I need a script to check its OS version and run accordingly.

Any help will be appreciated.

Cheers,
BVN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the others have said, you use some command, like `uname -m` to find out the OS version, then you use that result to run the appropriate script.

```
if [ `uname -m` eq 'i686-64' ]; then
    exec myscript-64
else
    exec myscript-32
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the output of `uname -m`.

Comment: Thanks Amber. am looking for a script which check its OS version and run the s cript